# App is not launched in iPad with Appium

Tags: ios, ipad, appium

I am new to both Appium and iOS and unable to get my app to launch with Appium on my iPad

I am trying to launch an app that is already installed on my iPad and click a button located in the app.  When I run this test no app is ever launched and not sure what I am missing.

My setup:

- iPad: 10.2
- Appium: 1.6
- XCode:  8.2.1
- I only have an .ipa file for my testing

Here is my code I am trying out.  I am assuming XCUITest is required with my setup versions.

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.After;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;

public class iOSTest {

    @Test
    public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "My iPad");
        capabilities.setCapability("udid", "UID_CODE");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersioin", "10.2");
        capabilities.setCapability("bundleId", "com.bundle.id");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", "--ipa /Users/me/Desktop/MyIpaFile.ipa");
        capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");

        IOSDriver driver = new IOSDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

}
```

Here is the error I am getting when running in Eclipse:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  /private/var/folders/1v/z4bcsphn11n38cs5hdnq7zkc7gwjdl/T/testng-eclipse-2119368657/testng-customsuite.xml

Jan 26, 2017 3:11:17 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Jan 26, 2017 3:11:18 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.
Jan 26, 2017 3:11:18 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection
FAILED: setUp
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{app=--ipa /Users/me/Desktop/MyIpaFile.ipa, platformVersioin=10.2, bundleId=com.bundle.id, automationName=XCUITest, udid=UID_CODE, platformName=iOS, deviceName=My iPad}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'myMachine.local', ip: '10.45.4.216', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.6', java.version: '1.8.0_92'
Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:91)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:69)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:40)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute(IOSDriver.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:141)
at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:36)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:114)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:132)
at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.<init>(IOSDriver.java:82)
at POC.iOSTest.setUp(iOSTest.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)
```

Comment: can you post the error appium is giving you?

Comment: @econoMichael, I have simplified the code to help pin-point my issues, but I am still uncertain what I am missing or how the `desiredCapabilities` are supposed to consist of